# How to use string template while using JSON?

Tags: reactjs, json, api, hasura, template-strings

I am working on a project and would like to use `prodConfig` or `draftConfig` according to few conditions. I am using Hasura and getting 2 different JSON responses with only 1 key different in the response i.e.`prodConfig` or `draftConfig`

Example:

`data.businesses_by_pk.draftConfig`
or
`data.businesses_by_pk.prodConfig`

So, I thought of using a string template ( ${} ) but that doesn't work:

Hence, I tried this:

```
let configFile = Object.keys(data.businesses_by_pk)[1]; //This gives either 'prodConfig' or 'draftConfig'
let header = data.businesses_by_pk.configFile;
```

But this returns undefined.

Please help me with this. Correct me If I am wrong somewhere, I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let header = data?.businesses_by_pk?.draftConfig || data?.businesses_by_pk?.prodConfig`

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to dig into the object. It won't error out, it will instead return `undefined`. You can then set a default when it does return undefined.

For example: `let names = (data?.name || data?.firstName) ?? 'smith'` Where `smith` will be the default if any of the names beforehand is `falsy`